Trouble using stockfish.js with typescript
I ran npm install stockfish and have the following simple file getBestMove.ts
import stockfish from 'stockfish';

const fen = '3r1r1k/pp2Nqbp/3Rb2p/2P1pp2/7P/N1P3P1/PP2QP2/R3K3 w - - 2 30'

interface TBestMoveResponse {
  bestMove: string | null;
}

export const getBestMove = async () => {
  const engine = stockfish();

  const details = await new Promise<TBestMoveResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
    let bestMove = null;

    engine.onmessage = (line: string) => {
      if (line.startsWith('bestmove')) {
        const tokens = line.split(' ');
        bestMove = tokens[1];

        resolve({ bestMove });
      }
    };

    engine.postMessage(`position fen ${fen}`);
    engine.postMessage(`go depth 20`);
  });

  engine.postMessage('quit');

  return details;

}

// stockfish.d.ts
declare module 'stockfish' {
  const stockfish: any;
  export default stockfish;
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types/libraries"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "include": ["index.ts", "src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

// webpack.config.cjs
const path = require('path');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  target: 'node',
  mode: slsw.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  node: false,
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        keep_classnames: true,
        keep_fnames: true,
      }
    }
    )],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.cjs', '.mjs', '.js', '.ts'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
      }),
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    path: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? path.join(__dirname, '.webpack') : path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
};

but when I build my project, I get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stockfish'. I haven't had this issue importing any other modules in my entire project so far and am not treating the stockfish module any differently.
The error message is quite large, but also includes:
no extension
                  <path>/node_modules/stockfish is not a file
                .cjs
                  <path>/node_modules/stockfish.cjs doesn't exist
                .mjs
                  <path>/node_modules/stockfish.mjs doesn't exist
                .js
                  <path>/node_modules/stockfish.js doesn't exist
                .ts



do those files exist in /node_modules?

So, I ran npm install stockfish, and the stockfish directory is certainly in /node_modules but the directory itself doesn’t have an index file; instead, it has  a few js files like build.js and an src directory

According to docs, it seems you need to build it.

Ah I saw that note, but didn't quite understand it. I've installed emscripten. I ran npm install stockfish, which added a stockfish directory to my node_modules; do I just run node_modules/stockfish/build.js, perhaps as a postinstall script? And then I'll be able to use it within my node.js files like import stockfish from 'stockfish';?
That's my hope; however, when I followed those steps and ran node_modules/stockfish/build.js, I'm getting an error: no such file or directory ... stockfish/src/misc.cpp
misc.cpp is in the repo on gh, but not present from npm install

I got it working this way:
import { createRequire } from "module"
import path from 'path';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)

const stockfish_path = path.join('node_modules', 'stockfish', 'src', 'stockfish-nnue-16.js')
const load_engine = require('./load_engine.cjs')

and then following this example from there
